# RegEx for capturing special chars

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to replace a string using regular expression what i need basically is to convert a code like assignment:

```
k*=i
```

into

```
k=k+i
```

In my example:

```
jregex.Pattern p=new jregex.Pattern("([a-z]|[A-Z])([a-z]|[A-Z]|\\d)*[\\+|\\*|\\-|\\/][=]([a-z]|[A-Z])*([a-z]|[A-Z]|\\d)");
Replacer r= new Replacer(p,"1=$1,2=$2,3=$3,4=$4,5=$5,6=$6,7=$7,8=$8");
String result=r.replace("k*=i");
```

The regex seems to not extract the special chars.

(in this example: +, -, *, /, =)

So what I get as result is:

```
1=k,2=,3=,4=i,5=,6=,7=,8=
```

(I can extract only the k & i)

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try it like this `([a-z])([*+-/])=(i)`  https://regex101.com/r/6bqXZ3/1 and replace with `$1=$1$2$3`

Answer (score 0):

You could use 3 capturing groups and capturing *+/- in a character class.

```
([a-zA-Z])([*+/-])=([a-zA-Z])
```

That will match:

- `([a-zA-Z])` Capture group 1, match a-z A-Z
- `([*+/-])` Capture group 2, match * + / -
- `=` Match literally
- `([a-zA-Z])` Capture group 3, match a-z A-Z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jKDmd9/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/yPTJQx)

And replace with:

```
$1=$1$2$3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can design as expression similar to:

```
(.+)[*+-/]=(.+)
```

where we are capturing our `k` and `i` using these two capturing groups in the start and end:

```
(.+)
```

We can add more boundaries, if we wish, such as start and end char:

```
^(.+)[*+-/]=(.+)$
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(.+)[*+-/]=(.+)";
final String string = "k*=i\n"
     + "apple*=orange";
final String subst = "$1=$1+$2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/OE2g2a/1)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]